# sort two completly different type of array with one common properties

Tags: arrays, swift

Hi I have two array with different properties and only properties has common `sort_order` and I want to merge this two array and want to sort this two array by `sort_order`.

Here is the code:

```
var array1:[AnyObject] = [{
    "name":"obj1Array1"
    "sort_order": 4
    "type":"G"
},{
    "name":"obj2Array1"
    "sort_order": 1
    "type":"G"
},{
    "name":"obj31Array1"
    "sort_order": 5
    "type":"G"
}]

var array2:[AnyObject] = [{
    "Group":"M"
    "sort_order": 3
    "type":"G"
},{
    "Group":"C"
    "sort_order": 2
    "type":"G"
},{
    "Group":"D"
    "sort_order": 6
    "type":"G"
}]
```

Comment: if you merge them both, how will you know which is an object of array1 and which is that of array2 when you use it? or is it like this: `name` from array1 is the same as `group` from array2?

Comment: because I already created model classes for this objects

Comment: For objects to be in the same array, they all have to be of the same type. So, if they are of the same type, say `Any`, how would you know which object is of which type when you want to access them from the said array.

Comment: you should be able to achieve that using protocol

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I guess, in good old Objective-C days, we could have used a sort predicate. 
Well, those days are behind us and protocols are ministers in new Swift government.

Lets see what protocols can do in this case.
You could define a protocol that has sort_order as a property.
This protocol needs to be conformed by both your object types (A and B in below code. Also, made them Codable for yet more protocol magic). 
Then you can create a merged array of type Ordered, and use sort function on that array.

```
protocol Ordered {
    var sort_order:Int{get}
}

struct A:Codable, Ordered {
    let name:String
    let sort_order:Int
    let type:String
}

struct B:Codable, Ordered {
    let Group:String
    let sort_order:Int
    let type:String
}

var array1:[A] = []
var array2:[B] = []

var mergedArray:[Ordered] = array1
for item in array2 {
    mergedArray.append(item)
}

mergedArray.sort { (A, B) -> Bool in
    return A.sort_order < B.sort_order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    var array1 : [[String : Any]] = [[  "name" : "obj1Array1", "sort_order" : 4, "type":"G" ],
                  [ "name":"obj2Array1","sort_order": 1,"type":"G"],
                  ["name":"obj31Array1","sort_order": 5,"type":"G"]]

    var array2 : [[String : Any]] = [[ "Group":"M", "sort_order": 3,"type":"G"],
                  ["Group":"C", "sort_order": 2,"type":"G"],
                  ["Group":"D","sort_order": 6,"type":"G"]]



    let newArr = [array1, array2].flatMap({$0}).sorted(by: { ($0["sort_order"] as! Int) < ($1["sort_order"] as! Int) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it using swift 4-

```
 var array1: [[String: Any]] = [
        ["name": "obj1Array1", "sort_order": 4, "type": "G"],
        ["name": "obj2Array1", "sort_order": 1, "type": "G"],
        ["name": "obj3Array1", "sort_order": 5, "type": "G"]
    ]

    var array2: [[String: Any]] = [
        ["Group": "M", "sort_order": 3, "type": "G"],
        ["Group": "C", "sort_order": 2, "type": "G"],
        ["Group": "D", "sort_order": 6, "type": "G"]
    ]

    let mergedArray = array1 + array2

    let sortedAndMerged = mergedArray.sorted{ ($0["sort_order"] as! Int) < ($1["sort_order"] as! Int) }

    print(sortedAndMerged)

// prints [["type": "G", "name": "obj2Array1", "sort_order": 1], ["Group": "C", "sort_order": 2, "type": "G"], ["Group": "M", "sort_order": 3, "type": "G"], ["type": "G", "name": "obj1Array1", "sort_order": 4], ["type": "G", "name": "obj3Array1", "sort_order": 5], ["Group": "D", "sort_order": 6, "type": "G"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
    let array1: [[String:Any]] = [ [
            "name":"obj1Array1",
            "sort_order": 4,
            "type":"G"
        ],
        [
            "name":"obj2Array1",
            "sort_order":1,
            "type":"G"
        ],
        [
            "name":"obj31Array1",
            "sort_order":5,
            "type":"G"

        ]]
    let array2: [[String:Any]] = [ [
            "Group":"M",
            "sort_order": 3,
            "type":"G"
        ],
        [
            "Group":"C",
            "sort_order": 2,
            "type":"G"
        ],
        [
            "Group":"D",
            "sort_order": 6,
            "type":"G"
        ]
    ]

    var new = array1 + array2
    new = new.sorted{
        ($0["sort_order"] as! Int) < ($1["sort_order"] as! Int)

        }

    print(new)
```